# Comparison between a folder and another one plus its subfolders content

Tags: windows, file-compare

My situation is this:

I have a simple SD Card full of photos and videos from my camera that date back to few years ago and I realized some pictures have never been imported to hard drive. Now I would like to compare all these GBs of photos to my pictures gallery in my hard drive, that consists of a folder with a lot of subfolders, in order to highlight the photos that have never been imported from my camera SD card and choose between them.

As simple a task as it may sound I didn't find a real way to do this.

I am a Windows user and I tried FreeFileSync which I've used a lot but, although actually capable of helping, it would require to manually add each subfolder to be compared and they're way too many in my case.

I also tried WinMerge that behaves almost the same way as FreeFileSync though it allows to automatically include subfolders in the comparison process.
Its issue is that it doesn't compare the source folder files to the destination subfolders but instead it only compares source folder's content to the destination folder's root content and then adds subfolders to the list as wholes without recognizing duplications to the source folder.
This is what would let me highlight those files that still need to be imported because they would be the only non duplicate files belonging to the source folder.
WinMerge's course of action with destination subfolders would be copying them as whole folders to the source path.

Then I tried some duplicate files finders because I needed some software that would keep memory of files content while comparing and the best pieces I found are Duplicate Cleaner Free and Easy Duplicate Finder. Both proved very useful in other situations where I had duplications scattered around the drive by iTunes that had completely spoiled my library.
Their problem is that they do recognize duplicate files pretty well but there is no way to show which files were NOT duplications.
However I found that Duplicate Cleaner Free allows you to export the list of duplicates to a CSV.

I am wondering if anybody knows a better way to accomplish this (maybe better software to use that I don't know of) or if somebody could help me understand if that CSV is actually useful.

I tried to export one list and the data provided is exhaustive but hard to use.
The trouble is that Duplicate Cleaner Free found many duplications from destination to destination as well so the CSV will list them too. This makes me think it wouldn't be easy to automate a process with that CSV but I may be wrong hopefully.

Thanks

---

If no Windows solutions exist I would be happy to find a Linux workaround for this problem. I'm able to do basic tasks in Linux.

---

I believed a picture could help so here is one

[image: situation]

I'd need a program that helps me do what I'm showing in this picture

Comment: It's possible that you somehow have two accounts.  You should be able to edit your own posts, but your attempt to add the diagram showed up as if it was submitted from another account.  You might want to check with a moderator to see what's going on and consolidate the accounts if needed.  It will affect access to your own posts and accumulating rep.

Answer (score 0):

Under Linux:

1. `cd /your/sd/path`
2. `ls > ~/sd-card.txt`
3. `cd /your/pictures/root/folder`
4. `ls */ > ~/hdd.txt`
   (this step may take some time)
5. `cd ~`
6. `sdiff sd-card.txt hdd.txt > comparison.txt`

You'll have the missing files on your left. You can use your text editor to have it highlight all the occurrences of the "<" symbol (the marker used to show there's a difference in the left-hand side file).

Should help!